# Reviving pandas KeyErrors seemingly at random, without changing my code. Possible memory errors?

Tags: python, csv, pandas, memory, keyerror

I'm working through a sklearn tutorial book, that had this section:

```
Next, we create a TfidfVectorizer. Recall from Chapter 3, Feature Extraction and Preprocessing, that TfidfVectorizer combines CountVectorizer and TfidfTransformer. We fit it with the training messages, and transform both the training and test messages:

>>> vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer()
>>> X_train = vectorizer.fit_transform(X_train_raw)
>>> X_test = vectorizer.transform(X_test_raw)
Finally, we create an instance of LogisticRegression and train our model. Like LinearRegression, LogisticRegression implements the fit() and predict() methods. As a sanity check, we printed a few predictions for manual inspection:

>>> classifier = LogisticRegression()
>>> classifier.fit(X_train, y_train)
>>> predictions = classifier.predict(X_test)
>>> for i, prediction in enumerate(predictions[:5]):
>>>     print 'Prediction: %s. Message: %s' % (prediction, X_test_raw[i])
The following is the output of the script:

Prediction: ham. Message: If you don't respond imma assume you're still asleep and imma start calling n shit
Prediction: spam. Message: HOT LIVE FANTASIES call now 08707500020 Just 20p per min NTT Ltd, PO Box 1327 Croydon CR9 5WB 0870 is a national rate call
Prediction: ham. Message: Yup... I havent been there before... You want to go for the yoga? I can call up to book 
Prediction: ham. Message: Hi, can i please get a  &lt;#&gt;  dollar loan from you. I.ll pay you back by mid february. Pls.
Prediction: ham. Message: Where do you need to go to get it?
```

And I followed along:

```
ddir = (sys.argv[1])


df = pd.read_csv(ddir + '/SMSSpamCollection', delimiter='\t', header=None)

#print df.head
#print 'Number of spam messages: ', df[df[0] == 'spam'][0].count()
#print 'Number of ham messages: ', df[df[0] == 'ham'][0].count()

X_train_raw, X_test_raw, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(df[1], df[0])

vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer()

X_train = vectorizer.fit_transform(X_train_raw)
X_test = vectorizer.transform(X_test_raw)


classifier = LogisticRegression()
classifier.fit(X_train, y_train)
predictions = classifier.predict(X_test)

for i, pdn in enumerate(predictions):
    print 'Prediction: %s. Message: %s' % (pdn, X_test_raw[i])
```

However, for some reason, this gave me an error. Thinking it was my modifications, I rewrote my code to follow the book line for line:

```
for i, prediction in enumerate(predictions[:5]):
    print 'Prediction: %s. Message: %s' % (prediction, X_test_raw[i])
```

and yet, this only printed two answers before crashing:

```
Number of spam messages: 747
Number of ham messages: 4825
['ham' 'ham' 'ham' ..., 'ham' 'ham' 'ham']
Prediction: ham. Message: Go until jurong point, crazy.. Available only in bugis n great world la e buffet... Cine there got amore wat...
Prediction: ham. Message: Ok lar... Joking wif u oni...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Chapter4[B-FLGTLG][Y-SF]--[DC].py", line 38, in <module>
    print 'Prediction: %s. Message: %s' % (prediction, X_test_raw[i])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/series.py", line 583, in __getitem__
    result = self.index.get_value(self, key)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/indexes/base.py", line 1980, in get_value
    tz=getattr(series.dtype, 'tz', None))
  File "pandas/index.pyx", line 103, in pandas.index.IndexEngine.get_value (pandas/index.c:3332)
  File "pandas/index.pyx", line 111, in pandas.index.IndexEngine.get_value (pandas/index.c:3035)
  File "pandas/index.pyx", line 159, in pandas.index.IndexEngine.get_loc (pandas/index.c:4018)
  File "pandas/hashtable.pyx", line 303, in pandas.hashtable.Int64HashTable.get_item (pandas/hashtable.c:6610)
  File "pandas/hashtable.pyx", line 309, in pandas.hashtable.Int64HashTable.get_item (pandas/hashtable.c:6554)
KeyError: 2
```

Now here's the problem: I ran the exact same script, without changing a single line, a second time, and it gave me a *different error*:

```
Number of spam messages: 747
Number of ham messages: 4825
['ham' 'ham' 'ham' ..., 'ham' 'ham' 'ham']
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Chapter4[B-FLGTLG][Y-SF]--[DC].py", line 38, in <module>
    print 'Prediction: %s. Message: %s' % (prediction, X_test_raw[i])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/series.py", line 583, in __getitem__
    result = self.index.get_value(self, key)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/indexes/base.py", line 1980, in get_value
    tz=getattr(series.dtype, 'tz', None))
  File "pandas/index.pyx", line 103, in pandas.index.IndexEngine.get_value (pandas/index.c:3332)
  File "pandas/index.pyx", line 111, in pandas.index.IndexEngine.get_value (pandas/index.c:3035)
  File "pandas/index.pyx", line 159, in pandas.index.IndexEngine.get_loc (pandas/index.c:4018)
  File "pandas/hashtable.pyx", line 303, in pandas.hashtable.Int64HashTable.get_item (pandas/hashtable.c:6610)
  File "pandas/hashtable.pyx", line 309, in pandas.hashtable.Int64HashTable.get_item (pandas/hashtable.c:6554)
KeyError: 0
```

How is this even possible? Do I have some low-level ram bug messing with python itself? The data is here: http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/SMS+Spam+Collection in case anyone wants to follow along.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UPDATE

I found a solution from here: [Problems with Pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29305131/problems-with-pandas?answertab=votes#tab-top)

I changed:

```
print 'Prediction: %s. Message: %s' % (pdn, X_test_raw[i])
```

to

```
print 'Prediction: %s. Message: %s' % (pdn, X_test_raw.iloc[i])
```

and now it works fine:

```
Number of spam messages: 747
Number of ham messages: 4825
['ham' 'spam' 'ham' ..., 'spam' 'ham' 'ham']
Prediction: ham. Message: Well done, blimey, exercise, yeah, i kinda remember wot that is, hmm. 
Prediction: spam. Message: U have won a nokia 6230 plus a free digital camera. This is what u get when u win our FREE auction. To take part send NOKIA to 83383 now. POBOX114/14TCR/W1 16
Prediction: ham. Message: I doubt you could handle 5 times per night in any case...
Prediction: ham. Message: I've told you everything will stop. Just dont let her get dehydrated.
Prediction: ham. Message: AH POOR BABY!HOPE URFEELING BETTERSN LUV! PROBTHAT OVERDOSE OF WORK HEY GO CAREFUL SPK 2 U SN LOTS OF LOVEJEN XXX.
```